# Send records to messaging queue using either of one policy

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

I have bunch of keys `(clientKey)` and values `(processBytes)` that I want to send to our messaging queue by packing them in one byte array. I will make one byte array of all the keys and values which should always be less than 50K and then send to our messaging queue.

For each partition, I have bunch of `dataHolders` so I am iterating those and then sending it to my messaging queue:-

```
private void validateAndSend(final DataPartition partition) {
  final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);

  // sending data via async policy but it can be send with other two sync queue policy as well.
  final Packet packet = new Packet(partition, new QPolicyAsync());

  DataHolder dataHolder;
  while ((dataHolder = dataHolders.poll()) != null) {
    packet.addAndSendJunked(dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        dataHolder.getProcessBytes());
  }
  packet.close();
}
```

**`Packet` class**: This class packs all the keys and values into one byte array and call corresponding implementation passed in the constructor to send data to queue.

```
public final class Packet implements Closeable {
  private static final int MAX_SIZE = 50000;
  private static final int HEADER_SIZE = 36;

  private final byte dataCenter;
  private final byte recordVersion;
  private final long address;
  private final long addressFrom;
  private final long addressOrigin;
  private final byte partition;
  private final byte replicated;
  private final ByteBuffer itemBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
  private final QueuePolicy policy;
  private int pendingItems = 0;

  public Packet(final DataPartition partition, final QueuePolicy policy) {
    this.partition = (byte) partition.getPartition();
    this.policy = policy;
    this.dataCenter = Utils.LOCATION.get().datacenter();
    this.recordVersion = 1;
    this.replicated = 0;
    final long packedAddress = new Data().packAddress();
    this.address = packedAddress;
    this.addressFrom = 0L;
    this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
  }

  private void addHeader(final ByteBuffer buffer, final int items) {
    buffer.put(dataCenter).put(recordVersion).putInt(items).putInt(buffer.capacity())
        .putLong(address).putLong(addressFrom).putLong(addressOrigin).put(partition)
        .put(replicated);
  }

  // sending here by calling policy implementation
  private void sendData() {
    if (itemBuffer.position() == 0) {
      // no data to be sent
      return;
    }
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
    addHeader(buffer, pendingItems);
    buffer.put(itemBuffer);
    // sending data via particular policy
    policy.sendToQueue(address, buffer.array());
    itemBuffer.clear();
    pendingItems = 0;
  }

  public void addAndSendJunked(final byte[] key, final byte[] data) {
    if (key.length > 255) {
      return;
    }
    final byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
    final byte dataLength = (byte) data.length;

    final int additionalSize = dataLength + keyLength + 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
    final int newSize = itemBuffer.position() + additionalSize;
    if (newSize >= (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      sendData();
    }
    if (additionalSize > (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      throw new AppConfigurationException("Size of single item exceeds maximum size");
    }

    final ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    final long timestamp = dataLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();
    // data layout
    itemBuffer.put((byte) 0).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(dataLength)
        .put(data);
    pendingItems++;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if (pendingItems > 0) {
      sendData();
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can send data to my messaging queue in three different ways so for that I created an interface and then having three different implementations:

**`QueuePolicy` interface**:

```
public interface QueuePolicy {
    public boolean sendToQueue(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords);
}
```

**`QPolicyAsync` class**:

```
public class QPolicyAsync implements QueuePolicy {

  @Override
  public boolean sendToQueue(long address, byte[] encodedRecords) {
    return SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueAsync(address, encodedRecords);
  }
}
```

**`QPolicySync` class**:

```
public class QPolicySync implements QueuePolicy {

  @Override
  public boolean sendToQueue(long address, byte[] encodedRecords) {
    return SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueSync(address, encodedRecords);
  }
}
```

**`QPolicySyncWithSocket` class**:

```
public class QPolicySyncWithSocket implements QueuePolicy {
  private final Socket socket;

  public QPolicySyncWithSocket(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean sendToQueue(long address, byte[] encodedRecords) {
    return SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueSync(address, encodedRecords, Optional.of(socket));
  }
}
```

The idea is very simple: I am sending data to my messaging queue via either of those three `QueuePolicy` implementations. It depends on how clients want to send data. As of now I am passing implementation of `QueuePolicy` in the `Packet` constructor and then sends data via that policy. Each `QueuePolicy` implementation calls corresponding method in `SendRecord` class.

---

Now I need to know whether data was successfully sent or not. As of now methods in `Packet` class doesn't return any boolean so I don't know whether it was successfully sent or not. I can have cases where `dataHolders` has only one element in it or it can have multiple elements in it.

```
private void validateAndSend(final DataPartition partition) {
  final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);

  // sending data via async policy but it can be send with other two sync queue policy as well.
  final Packet packet = new Packet(partition, new QPolicyAsync());

  DataHolder dataHolder;
  while ((dataHolder = dataHolders.poll()) != null) {
    packet.addAndSendJunked(dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        dataHolder.getProcessBytes());
  }
  packet.close();
  // how do I know whether this data was successfully sent?

}
```

If I return boolean from `addAndSendJunked` and `close` method in Packet class, then which boolean value I need to rely on? Because either of these two methods can send the data.

- `close` method will send data either there is only one element in it or there was left over elements.
- `addAndSendJunked` method will send data as soon as limit is reached.

**Update:**

Below is my updated code:

```
public final class Packet implements Closeable {
  private static final int MAX_SIZE = 50000;
  private static final int HEADER_SIZE = 36;
  private boolean result = false;

  private final byte dataCenter;
  private final byte recordVersion;
  private final long address;
  private final long addressFrom;
  private final long addressOrigin;
  private final byte partition;
  private final byte replicated;
  private final ByteBuffer itemBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
  private final QueuePolicy policy;
  private int pendingItems = 0;

  public Packet(final DataPartition partition, final QueuePolicy policy) {
    this.partition = (byte) partition.getPartition();
    this.policy = policy;
    this.dataCenter = Utils.LOCATION.get().datacenter();
    this.recordVersion = 1;
    this.replicated = 0;
    final long packedAddress = new Data().packAddress();
    this.address = packedAddress;
    this.addressFrom = 0L;
    this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
  }

  private void addHeader(final ByteBuffer buffer, final int items) {
    buffer.put(dataCenter).put(recordVersion).putInt(items).putInt(buffer.capacity())
        .putLong(address).putLong(addressFrom).putLong(addressOrigin).put(partition)
        .put(replicated);
  }

  // sending here by calling policy implementation
  private void flush() {
    if (itemBuffer.position() == 0) {
      // no data to be sent
      return true;
    }
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
    addHeader(buffer, pendingItems);
    buffer.put(itemBuffer);
    // sending data via particular policy
    boolean sent = policy.sendToQueue(address, buffer.array());
    itemBuffer.clear();
    pendingItems = 0;
    return sent;
  }

  public void addAndSendJunked(final byte[] key, final byte[] data) {
    if (key.length > 255) {
      result = false;
      return;
    }
    final byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
    final byte dataLength = (byte) data.length;

    final int additionalSize = dataLength + keyLength + 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
    final int newSize = itemBuffer.position() + additionalSize;
    if (newSize >= (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      result = flush();
    }
    if (additionalSize > (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      throw new AppConfigurationException("Size of single item exceeds maximum size");
    }

    final ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    final long timestamp = dataLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();
    // data layout
    itemBuffer.put((byte) 0).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(dataLength)
        .put(data);
    pendingItems++;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if (pendingItems > 0) {
      result = flush();
    }
  }

  public boolean getResult() {
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a boolean from the `close()` method because it's overriden.

You have different options there:

1. throw an exception whenever a send returns false
2. return a boolean from `sendData`, that I would rename to `flush` and make it public (see below), and return a boolean from `addAndSendJunked` as well.
3. add a boolean field in class `Packet` and a getter to be able to get its value at any time

Method `flush`:

```
public boolean flush() {
    if (itemBuffer.position() == 0) {
        // no data to be sent
        return true;
    }
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
    addHeader(buffer, pendingItems);
    buffer.put(itemBuffer);
    // sending data via particular policy
    boolean result = policy.sendToQueue(address, buffer.array());
    itemBuffer.clear();
    pendingItems = 0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why `flush` method needs to be public here? In my case, no one is calling that method from outside of `Packet` class. Also I updated the question with your suggestion. Do you think that's right or I can have some other changes as well? I am returning a boolean from flush method and having a boolean variable in `Packet` class and its getter as well.

Comment: @user1950349 `flush` is public because it is used in `close` that cannot return a boolean. `flush` should be call directly should you want to know the result of a send.